# What is the meaning of "very near the surface"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the "very near the surface" in the following sentence:

> At first, I found her gravity rather intimidating; but, as I saw more of her, I found that jocularity was very near the surface.

Answer (score 2):

As the narrator came to know her better, they found that she isn't really intimidating, she's actually playful once you peel the first layers.

**Very near the surface** here means once you know her **just a little**, you don't need to dig deep to find the playful side of her.